# воспроизведение mp3 файла с android через браузер компьютера по wifi

Tags: android, wifi, mp3, браузер

Есть задача у меня написать приложение на android. Аудиоплеер.
У него должна быть такая фича: воспроизведение аудиофайлов на компьютере через браузер по Wi-Fi

Работать должно например так:

Сижу я такой слушаю плеер в наушниках. А у меня компьютер с подключенной системой 5.1 и захотел я через колонки послушать музыку. Нажимаю кнопку, телефон становится web-сервером.

На компьютере в адресной строке открываю страницу типа 
"вась-вась.телефон.ru:8080" и там что-то типа файлового менеджера. и я могу слушать музыку на компе, но она на телефоне.

НО!

Еще должна быть возможность управлять воспроизведением с телефона (перемотка, строп, вперед, назад, громкость)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону смотреть. Какую технологию изучить?
Может есть где примеры?

Comment: в таком случае, как я считаю, нет смысла писать какие-то отдельные приложения. Всё, что вам нужно: файловый менеджер ES проводник или ему подобные, в котором уже есть возможность создания FTP сервера. Активируйте FTP, заходите по адресу на компьютере с помощью проводника или браузера и всё, вы имеете доступ к ФС вашего телефона.

Comment: Как-то много телодвижений получается. Может лучше задействовать блютуз - там есть протокол, по которому компьютер может быть в роли блютуз-колонок. При этом переключение на аудио систему компьютера можно будет сделать в одно касание.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону технологий [DLNA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA) и/или [UPnP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP) - DLNA более предпочтителен.

На гитхабе достаточно либ и API с поддержкой обоих технологий - [втыкаем](https://github.com/search?l=Java&o=desc&q=DLNA&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93)